# Add a Left Join to the result of a two table Select

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, left-join

Ok if I have the following select statement for two tables:

```
SELECT shipments.ShipmentID, shipments.Name, shipments.Reference_No As [Reference Number], shipments.Qty, shipments.Status, 
       Shipment_Details.ISBN, Shipment_Details.Title, Shipment_Details.Author, Shipment_Details.Publisher, 
FROM shipments, Shipment_Details 
WHERE shipments.Shipment_No = Shipment_Details.Shipment_No AND shipments.Order_No = Shipment_Details.Order_No 
               AND  ((Shipment_Details.Order_No=@Order_No))
```

How can I do a left join with a Table called `ShippingSystemExport`, and when the shipments.ShipmentID is found in `ShippingSystemExport` AND the shipments.Status (From the original query) is NOT "Shipped" then have the value of shipents.ShipmentID return as "Scanned in Shipping Department"

Comment: Is there any reason that a C# tag used here?

Comment: Why are you left joining ShippingSystemExport if your condition is that `ShipmentID` exists in `ShippingSystemExport`?  Why not just use an `INNER JOIN` in that case (assuming `ShipmentID` is the field you're joining on)?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirement correctly, the following query should do the work. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

```
SELECT 'Scanned in Shipping Department' AS ShipmentID, shipments.Name, shipments.Reference_No As [Reference Number], shipments.Qty, shipments.Status, 
   Shipment_Details.ISBN, Shipment_Details.Title, Shipment_Details.Author, Shipment_Details.Publisher, 
FROM shipments
INNER JOIN Shipment_Details ON shipments.Shipment_No = Shipment_Details.Shipment_No AND shipments.Order_No = Shipment_Details.Order_No AND ((Shipment_Details.Order_No=@Order_No)) 
LEFT JOIN ShippingSystemExport ON ShippingSystemExport.ShipmentID = shipments.ShipmentID
WHERE shipments.Status <> 'Shipped'
```

However, why is "Scanned in Shipping Department" returned as ShipmentID? Just wonder...

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you're looking for:

```
SELECT a.ShipmentID, a.Name, a.Reference_No As [Reference Number], a.Qty, a.Status, 
b.ISBN, b.Title, b.Author, b.Publisher, a.ShipmentID AS [Scanned in Shipping Department]
FROM shipments a
INNER JOIN Shipment_Details b
ON a.Shipment_No=b.Shipment_No AND a.Order_No = b.Order_No AND
INNER JOIN ShippingSystemExport c
ON a.ShipmentID=c.ShipmentID AND a.Status <> 'Shipped'
WHERE b.Order_No=@Order_No AND c.ShipmentID
```

I used an `INNER JOIN` instead of a `LEFT JOIN` like I stated in my comment beneath your question.